# G*Power sample size calculation for ANOVA

Tags: anova, sample-size, gpower

I'm trying to do an a priori power calculation with G*Power 3.1.9.2, but I don't know which test to choose and what to enter in "number of groups" and "number of measurements" for my case.

**What I want to do:**

I want to pretest vignettes for my study. I combine 3x3 factors (e.g.: A,B,C x 1,2,3) in my vignettes and therefore have a total of 9 vignettes.

I would now like to test in advance whether the description of the vignettes matches the factors for which I have constructed them. (For example, I have a vignette that should contain the factors A and 1).

To do this, I would like to show all participants (1 group) each individual vignette (9 vignettes) and have them rate their agreement with all questions on the factors (2x3 questions).

**Example:** Vignette 1: "Blablabla.."

a) "This vignette describes A." strongly disagree (1) - strongly agree (7)

b) "This vignette describes B." strongly disagree (1) - strongly agree (7)

c) "This vignette describes C." strongly disagree (1) - strongly agree (7)

and

d) "This vignette describes 1." strongly disagree (1) - strongly agree (7)

e) "This vignette describes 2." strongly disagree (1) - strongly agree (7)

f) "This vignette describes 3." strongly disagree (1) - strongly agree (7)

Let's assume that vignette 1 should correspond  to factors A and 1.
For factor A: I would like to compare the mean values of a), b) and c) and assume that the mean value of a) is significantly higher than that of b) and c).

For factor 1: I would like to compare the mean values of d), e) and f) separately from factor A and assume that the mean value of d) is significantly higher than that of b) and c).

I would like to do this for all 9 vignettes individually.

**Which statistical test?**
Since I want to compare 3 means, I want to use an ANOVA. The design is within subject (all subjects answer all questions for all vignettes), therefore it should be repeated measures ANOVA.

**My questions:**
I want to know how big my sample size should be for this pretest --> G*Power a priori power calculation

(1) Which repeated measures ANOVA should I choose in G*Power?

(2) What do I have to enter in the options "number of groups" and "number of measurements"? (If I enter 1 for "Group", it does not work).